# Array Exercise Confusion

Tags: java, arrays, variables, methods

I have written a (so far incomplete) method that should take an array of ints, find the difference between neighboring cells, and then return the smallest difference.

For example:

[9, 16, 4, 8, 20] --> 7, 12, 4, 12 --> 4

[12, 21, 33, 6, 3, 3] --> 9, 12, 27, 3, 0 --> 0

Here's my method:

```
public static int minGap(int[] a) {
    int gap = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (a.length - 1) ; i++) {
        gap = Math.abs(a[i + 1] - a[i]);
        System.out.println(gap);
    }
    return gap;
}
```

I believe that I have the intermediate step correct (finding the differences), but I cannot figure out how to then compare all them and produce the smallest one. I'm assuming I will use an if-statement, but I only have the one variable "gap" to work with.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Don't compare them all. Store the first result in a variable, and compare the following results to that variable. Replace variable result if the current result is smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a new variable for the smallest gap found so far.  It can be initialized to something huge, probably `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

In the loop, if the current gap is smaller than the smallest gap found so far, then set the smallest gap found so far to the current gap.  Then after the `for` loop completes, you have the smallest gap.

Comment: This is a bit cleaner than @peter.petrov's solution, because by initializing to Integer.MAX_VALUE, you avoid the necessity of treating the first gap specially.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a min variable and update it as needed.

```
public static int minGap(int[] a) {
    int gap = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (a.length - 1) ; i++) {
        gap = Math.abs(a[i + 1] - a[i]);
        if (i==0 || gap < min) min = gap;
        System.out.println(gap);
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you always need to check if `i` is equals to `0`.